# Error fetching data through database in django

Tags: python, django

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    all_employee = employee.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for employee in all_employee:
        url = 'mainpage/' + str(employee.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href ="' + url + '">' + url + '</a><br>'
        return HttpResponse(html)

def details(request, id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>This is the details for" + str(id) + " </h2>")
```

The line `all_employee = employee.objects.all()` is giving the error and when I use this command in shell it is giving this:

```
[<employee: employee object>, <employee: employee object>, <employee: employee object>]
```

Instead of each row data.

Comment: please, share the error as well the code in a readable manner.

Comment: this is the error  local variable 'employee' referenced before assignment

Comment: Have searched for this error message ? You should have found a LOT of answers already...

Answer (score 0):

You are violating Django's MVT pattern, but let's skip this for now.

1. You need to import `Employee` model class (first letter capitalized if there is no other reason).
2. Even if you've imported model and made query, only one record will be rendered. You need to dedent `return HttpResponse(html)` verily on same level with for statement.